# Self-Descriptive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A self-descriptive number is a number that describes itself in a way so that if a number was 54513, it would mean that there would be 5 zeroes, as corresponding to the 1st digit, 4 ones, as corresponding to the 2nd digit, and so on.

What I want to know is if there is a process that can find the value of a self describing number with out guesswork.

Comment: These are called self-descriptive numbers; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number).

Comment: Thats right- will do

Comment: Here is the full list : $1210$, $2020$, $21200$, $3211000$, $42101000$, $521001000$, $6210001000$.

Comment: Umm 3211000 is that number

Comment: @user236182 https://oeis.org/A046043

Comment: @Esperluet - it's not a full list. for example `21100`,  `51000100`,  `610000100`, `7100000100`, `910000000100` and more :)

Comment: I've created a generator, for fun: https://yaireo.github.io/self-descriptive-numbers